# Why `Flutter Doctor` and `New Application Project` fails in my VSCode setup?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Following [these directions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode), like:

**Install the Flutter and Dart plugins**

1. Start VS Code.
2. Invoke View > Command Palette….
3. Type “install”, and select Extensions: Install Extensions.
4. Type “flutter” in the extensions search field, select Flutter in the list, and click Install. This also installs the required Dart plugin.

**Validate your setup with the Flutter Doctor**

1. Invoke View > Command Palette….
2. Type “doctor”, and select the Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor.
3. Review the output in the OUTPUT pane for any issues. Make sure to select Flutter from the dropdown in the different Output Options.

Step 3 of validate instructions results with OUTPUT:

[image]

I did install flutter, and `flutter doctor` in a new command shell gives result:

[image]

What am I missing here?  I also try VSCode extension palette command `Flutter: New Application Project` and that also fails with:

[image]

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: No device installed is related to adb, you have to install adb, either through command line, or through plugins, also . Try `flutter upgrade` and also `adb` (what output do you get?) in your terminal. If nothing works try to install flutter through android studio or terminal works better

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed Git and that you can access it from the command line. Check your PATH. Flutter SDK directory should be present there.

If that does not work, you should try to reinstall the dart and flutter extension.

Next Step should be to reinstall flutter.

Comment: git is installed.  say i open a command window and run `git --version`, i will get output like `git version 2.28.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that my attempt to support multiple flutter versions might be going outside of the conventions supported by [the Flutter extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter).

Here's what's up!... If you think you're smart like me and installed different versions of flutter in folders like `c:\src\flutter\1.20.2` and `c:\src\flutter\1.22.6`, then you can forget it because the extension is smarter than us, and will ignore this regardless of our `PATH` assignment.

Copying contents of my flutter install from `c:\src\flutter\1.22.6` to the parent folder `c:\src\flutter` resolved my issue. I need to review how to easily support different versions of flutter. Hmmm..

BTW... what I realized in retrospect is that the complaint about git is raised by the extension not finding the `.git` folder under the flutter folder (i.e. `c:\src\flutter`) that it presumed as the path to my flutter install. Well duh!!  That's because I want flutter to be sourced at the versioned sub-folder (i.e. `c:\src\flutter\1.22.6`).  Oh well.

Some scenarios I am left pondering:

1. How to correctly support multiple flutter installations while also benefiting from the extension (is there a way to configure this extension or my environment as a whole)?
2. Are my expectations to support multiple flutter installations unreasonable?
3. If my expectations are reasonable, and there are no known or documented way to support multiple flutter installations while also using this extension, then perhaps the extension has a bug?